# Thousands of bootstrap-switch: Forced reflow is a likely performance bottleneck

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-switch

I have thousands of [bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/Bttstrp/bootstrap-switch) as table row, like code below.
It's very expensive too load and if I see on ChromeDevTool (performance) I can see:
**Warning** Forced reflow is a likely performance bottleneck.

How can I make it faster? The time spent for rendering is too much and it breaks the page.

```
$("input[data-toggle='toggle']").bootstrapSwitch({
        onSwitchChange:function(event, state) {
            $(this).parents('form').trigger('change')
        }
    });
```

Table with +1.000 rows

```
<table>
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>
           <form action="...:">
               <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toogle"/>
             </form>
   </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to give them a fixed width? And prehaps its possible to group them in harmonica or tabuar items?

Comment: Which element should I add the fixed width on?

Comment: I would put it first on the <td> than the <form> and than the <input> and test each step.

Comment: Tried. Nothing changed.I've added the screenshot

Comment: As workaround, use table pagination. from UX perspective, it doesn't make sense to render a table with +1000 rows one time.

Comment: Yes I am using datatable, it should shows only 25 rows.